Opamp Input Noise Source?
Team, I have this basic opamp circuit:

However, I see a harmonics in input (VAC-IN, green) that's being amplified in the output (VAC-OUT, yellow):


This 'noise' is not present when signal generator output is plugged in direct to oscilloscope. Where is this 'noise' coming from?
Update: scope shot with no signal generator connected:

Where is this coming from?
Update2: no signal generator connected. Green is +12VDC while yellow is VAC-OUT. So it looks like noise is from voltage regulator:


How to address this?
Update 27-08-2024: sort of fixed now. noise pulse still there but pk-pk now reduced from 1.9V to 0.4V. somehow, chassis ground was connected to GND.
thanks all.

Have you learned why it's there yet? by proper measurements? I doubt the DC has 1Vpp noise differential on it when measured properly. Do you get 0V on every ground location?

The datasheet says 150mVpp max, which tells me your measurement method may be wrong or you have a load generating noise.  https://www.simpex.ch/en/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2021/12/Datasheet-ECLB75W.pdf

322kHz. Looks very much like switching regulator noise.

What switching supplies do you have connected or nearby that are not disclosed in the schematic? Including any test equipment, of course.

But why is it present? Because the assumption that all grounds before being connected were 0 V was false.

Identify the source and it will be easier to tell if it is conducted or radiated noise.

If you disconnect everything from the input side of the circuit, including oscilloscope and signal generator, and the noise goes away (or is greatly diminished), then the noise is likely being picked up in the wiring of those devices to your amplifier.
Try switching off everything in the vicinity, like lights, TV, computer etc., and repeat the experiment. Many things have "stand-by" power, so when I say switch off, I really mean unplug. Switch them all back on one by one until you see the noise return, and you have found the culprit. My first guess would be LED lighting.
If it turns out that you are picking up noise from outside sources, then your solutions are as usual, shorter and more careful signal routing, shielding and filtering.

This noise comes from poor AC grounding your circuit from the floating DC supply. An unbalanced input converts current * Z(f) into a voltage.
A true differential amplifier might use an INA IC or an INstrument Amplifier is balanced and less likely to be affected by a ground shift. But routing is important directly to the source.
Since your differential amplifier is ground-referenced and ground by definition should be 0V, there must be something wrong with this assumption.  By detecting the difference in each ground or the current created by connecting each "ground" you might detect the fault.
Since the DSO does not detect the noise directly, they must share a common ground and your circuit is the odd one with a "different" ground.
As it is a current feedback amplifier, there must be a difference in the ground potentials and voltage amplification.
ACDC PSUs normally conduct ground current using a PI filter with Y caps to PE gnd.
Floating DC supplies are often susceptible to PE-conducted filter noise.
UPDATE
The feedthrough switching noise in the DCDC regulator power transformer is not isolated even though at DC it is isolated. To resolve EMI issues, the OEM has recommended filter components application note. This noise often occurs due to lack of cross-winding balance caps to null feedthru common-mode capacitance. This issue is often amplified by miniature transformers with high interwinding capacitance.  This is a miniature 75 DC-DC converter. 
Good luck.


DSO ground is connected to circuit GND.

Yes but what is the Vac between Generator and circuit ground?

generator ground is connected to circuit GND as well as shown in J? connection in the circuit.

Yes this is called a ground loop with an unbalanced input amplifier.  Not 60 Hz but SMPS ground filter noise.  https://www.audiosciencereview.com/forum/index.php?attachments/1556412152409-png.25409/

thanks! update 2 added above. with no generator connected, 'noise' is still present. looks like from dc regulator.

PSRR is > 60 dB ?  Is noise common or differential mode?  I think it is a common mode and thus an unbalanced input amplifies the noise. Thus not the DC regulator noise but the AC Y-Cap filter to PE gnd.

thanks, let me remove that cap.

no difference. just noted that noise arises when opamp output is turned on via SD pin... when off, no noise in the output and power rail lines (+12V, -12V).

I still believe you have a conducted feedthru noise issue (CM noise) that contributes to CM ground and supply noise and poor CMRR in your circuit.
